# Movie Maker Transcoder high network usage, why?

Tags: networking, windows-movie-maker

I just recently noticed Movie Maker uses a lot of network while importing video files into a project.

[image]

Does this mean all my files will get uploaded to and encoded/converted by Microsoft servers?

Comment: Are you sure the videos you are importing are not on a shared network drive?

Comment: How could I be that stupid..